# Setting the directories for Quarto documents in Rstudio

Tags: directory, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I am currently trying to transition to Quarto from Rmarkdown. However, I am facing an issue with setting the correct project directory. I wanted to ask if there is something similar to this option in Rmarkdown with Quarto.
[image]

My understanding is that I need to make a `.yml` file to specify the directory I want to use, which is not very straightforward for me.

Comment: You could just make a new project in a new directory and create a new Quarto file

Comment: Yes I know, but I am wondering if there is a way to flexibly edit the directory of the output of the Quarto file rendering in the file itself without using a separate config file.

Comment: Maybe look at the `here` package, which makes all paths relative to the project root

Comment: It's been a couple months. Do you have any updates on a way to make this work?

Comment: I didn't have the reputation to comment. Here is a link to the quarto documentation referenced by @pablo-velázquez: https://quarto.org/docs/books/book-output.html#output-path

Answer (score 8):

You may want to use `{here}` package which is really useful for working with filepaths within projects.

Suppose I have created a quarto project within Rstudio by following `File -> New Project -> New Directory -> Quarto Project` and made some folders and files within it. Therefore my current project structure looks like

```
$
│ test_proj.Rproj
│ _quarto.yml
│
├─-data
│    mtcars.csv
│
└─-scripts
     delete.qmd
```

Now to invoke the `mtcars.csv` file from `delete.qmd` you can do the following

````
---
title: "Test File"
format: html
---

## Quarto

```{r reading-data}

df <- read.csv(here::here("data/mtcars.csv"))
```
````

As per the documentation of `here::here()`

> it will always locate the files relative to your project root

So thinking in terms of the project root (where the `test_proj.Rproj` is), you write the path of `mtcars.csv` in your `qmd` or `R-script` files as `"data/mtcars.csv"` and It doesn't matter where the script files are, since you are invoking the csv files relative to the project root which is fixed within a project.

To know more about `{here}`, see [here](https://here.r-lib.org/)

Comment: How do you publish to RStudio Connect using this directory structure and `server: shiny`?

Comment: @GiovanniColitti, Haven't used Rstudio Connect so far. So couldn't say much in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `output-file:` ex: `output-file: Projects/index.qmd` this will save your current file to the directory, but a basic level of Parent/child and absolute/relative paths would be required.

Currently this is an empty directory.

[image]

Then a simple example is:

```
---
output-file: test/index.qmd
---
```

Which then renders the file to the specified directory

[image]

Keep in mind my `delete.qmd` is saved to my Desktop, then I have it output another file in `/test` directory and have Quarto save the output as another file name. this doesn't need another YAML file, we use inline YAML

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! My problem actually is not with outputting, it's about invoking or calling files. For instance, I want to save `delete.qmd` inside a folder called `scripts` and this `scripts` folder is a part of my R project. Suppose I am working on `delete.qmd`, and I want to call a `something.csv` file located in a folder called `data`, which is also in my project directory. I would like to do so by writing `read_csv("data/something.csv")`. From what I see, this is not possible unless the `data` folder is inside the same folder the Quarto file is stored in.

Answer (score 2):

You can [add global knitr options in the document yaml](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html#knitr-options):

```
---
title: "My Document"
format: html
knitr:
  opts_knit:
    root.dir: "c:/my/project/directory"
---
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Still had to use `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/path/to/dir')` from within a chunk... Any ideas?

Comment: apparently related docs: https://quarto.org/docs/books/book-output.html#output-path

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I solved this as follows:

1. Create a Quarto Project directly form RStudio (go to File : New Project… command, specify New Directory, then choose Quarto Project).
2. When your Quarto Project is created, it will have a "_quarto" YAML file.
3. Open it with a text editor and add the next line just below title:
   output-dir: output
4. Create a new directory called "output" inside your Quarto Project.
5. Your files will be rendered in the new "output" directory!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use:

```r
quarto::quarto_render(here::here("path_to/doc.qmd"),
                      execute_dir = here::here(),
                      output_format = "all", as_job = TRUE)
```

I am using this to get output in multiple formats and found that setting `execute_dir` made the file paths work