# Setting working directory for interactive computations (ie., not render) in a Quarto document

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

Is there a way to reproduce the functionality of `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/path/to/dir')` from Rmarkdown (which does work in Quarto as well, when ran from a chunk) but straight from the YAML block? Something like:

```
---
knitr:
  options:
    root.dir: "/path/to/dir"
---
```

(I've tried it, and also substituting `options` with `opts_knit`, and it doesn't work either way.

Thank you!

Comment: Alternative option could be using [quarto project](https://quarto.org/docs/tools/rstudio.html#projects) with [`execute_dir`](https://quarto.org/docs/projects/code-execution.html#working-dir) option set as "project"  and with `{here}` package and [see this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73244900/10858321)

Comment: @shafee that works only when rendering the final document. But not when interactively executing chunks in a Qmd document (ie., using it as an R Notebook)

Comment: Can you add the code that worked (i.e. code of using `opts_knit` in a chunk)

Comment: @shafee I posted it in the OP: `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/path/to/dir')`

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but wondering if that code worked by specifying once in the setup chunk then why you would want that thing in yaml? I mean in both cases you have to specify it only once.

Comment: That's true, but the YAML version would be way more idiomatic and easy to remember. The current working method looks a bit hacky and against Quarto principles, which are based on hassle-free reproducible research. Doc configuration belong in the YAML block, not in a code chunk.